# Add different color in dropdownList Item from database values

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, styles

I have one dropdown .this dropdown are bind from database

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AcademicAchievementColor, Model.BindRatings, "Select" })
```

`AcademicAchievement` and `BindRatings` is my model properties

And i assign the values in controller

```
schoolPerformanceModel.BindRatings = new SelectList(performanceRepository.GetRatings(), "RatingId", "RatingName");
```

.the database values are

```
1)Exceeds
2)Meets
3)Approaching
4)Does Not Meet
```

I using jquery for change color

See below way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (document).ready(function() {
        $('#AcademicAchievementColor option:Exceeds').css('background-color', '#Red');
        $('#AcademicAchievementColor option:Meets').css('background-color', 'Green');
        $('#AcademicAchievementColor option:Approaching').css('background-color', '#Yellow');
        $('#AcademicAchievementColor option:Does Not Meet').css('background-color', 'Blue');
    });
</script>
```

But ,It's not working. have you any idea for this ?

Comment: Correct the typo `$(document).ready(..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#AcademicAchievementColor option[value=Exceeds]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Unless you have a select with id="AcademicAchievementColor", and you call your script after the DOM is constructed, it must work. You can also do it via css #AcademicAchievementColor option[value=Exceeds] { background:red;}

Comment: Ya i know i do correct.but it's not worked.if i has any script problem ?

Comment: I have one question. how to set disable hover in dropdown?